# Theming android application

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an android application with me for which I need to provide users an option to select a theme.

Right now I am putting color to an object using the code

```
android:textColor="@color/light_red"
```

I have many such places I have used these type of colors.

**Is there a way I could change the color value according to the selected theme?**

I checked out styling, but my problem is I might have 5 different text colors in my application but I might need to change it to entirely new set of colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one way. I don't know it's better way but it's worked for me.

For this you have to create a `Static` String for storing `selected_theme_str` and then based on this `selected_theme_str` you'll load color dynamically. like

```
String selected_theme_str="Light_red";
```

Check this string in your `Activity` and load `TextView` color based on this like

```
if(selected_theme_str.equals("Light_red")) 
{
 text_view.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_red));
}
else if(selected_theme_str.equals("Dark_red")) 
{
 text_view.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
}........
```

Comment: This is easily possible. But I will have to do it via code. I need to do it via the xml

Comment: @GeoPaul Via `XML` i don't think it's possible.

Comment: @M D seems like you are true.. I thought about android styling and theming will get to work. But it has limitations. will have to do it your way only

Answer (score 0):

add to your colors.xml something like this

```
<color name="firstColor">@color/red</color>
<color name="secondColor">@color/blue</color>
...
```

and use it your styles

or you can do it by theme attribute:
add to attrs.xml something like this

```
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="firstColor" format="reference|color"/>
    <attr name="secondColor" format="reference|color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and in your theme

```
<item name="firstColor">@color/red</item>
```

and in your layout

```
android:textColor="?attr/firstColor"
```

Comment: for example android:textColor="@color/firstColor"